# Installing Params::Validate with cpan - Unable to start 'Build'

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan, failed-installation

I'm trying to install Bugzilla for demo purposes on my Win8 PC using cygwin. I'm stuck at installing Perl modules, more specifically Params::Validate.

I've tried

> install-module.pl Params::Validate

and with cpan:

> install Params::Validate

The error message I get is following (in short):

> Running Build install
>   Unable to start 'Build': There is no application associated with the given file name extension.
>   DROLSKY/Params-Validate-1.13.tar.gz
>   sudo ./Build install  -- NOT OK
>   Failed during this command:
>   DROLSKY/Params-Validate-1.13.tar.gz          : install NO

The error message is quite simple and clear, but I have absolutely no clue where to find an application which should be associated with the 'Build'-file. Google couldn't help me either. Anyone of you can?

PS. Avast moved some files to quarantine earlier during the installation. I disabled the file monitoring from Avast and re-ran the installation of those modules (at least Module::Runtime) and got response that it went OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download `Params-Validate-1.13.tar.gz` and extract the contents to a temporary directory. Open the command line in that temporary directory and type:

```
perl Build.PL
```

This generates a file called `Build`. Now to actually build the module run:

```
./Build
```

Hopefully you don't get any nasty-sounding error messages. Before installing the module, let's test it works:

```
./Build test
```

Hopefully the test suite passes. Now you can install the module. You will need to run this as a user who has write permission over your Perl library directories. (On Linux/Unix machines, that might involve using `sudo`.) To install the module, run:

```
./Build install
```

All done.

Comment: That did the trick. I actually found that the Module::Runtime hadn't been installed properly, but with this approach I managed to install them both. Many thanks.